# ScheduledAgent user notification

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have background task in windows phone 7 app.

```
 PeriodicTask periodicTask = new PeriodicTask("TheWorker");
    periodicTask.Description = "The worker task";
    periodicTask.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

    ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);
    btnStartStopBgTask.Content = "Stop Background Task";
    isBackgroundTaskEnebaled = true;
```

The app does a few tasks .

Is there a way to send notification to user when the app is not open from the background ?

As we have in android..

Say in the background it checks something over the internet and finds out something interesting to be notified to the user. can it do?

Comment: You can use a Toast msg from your task. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487170%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Comment: http://www.31a2ba2a-b718-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66.com/2011/11/simple-wp7-mango-app-for-background.html found more link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can send a message to the user if your app is not running with a BackgroundAgent, and you could create a live tile too and show the news there or tell the user there is news.

[BackgroundAgent example](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/25/31-days-of-mango-day-25-background-agents/)